# Turn a wpdb query result that reveals one row into individual variables (using shortcodes if that matters)

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, wordpress

First post on stackoverflow.  I have been following this site for a long time, and usually find what im looking for.  But this has me perplexed.

Let me set the stage.  I am developing a web driven program.  I have Wordpress, with the Divi theme from Elegant Themes. and I am using shortcodes to insert into the modules. I am a newbie (this says it all.)

Here is my problem.  I have run a wpdb query that returns a single row of results.

```
$editresult = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT `serialnumber`, `batttype`, `cells`, `fullvolts` FROM listbattery WHERE serialnumber = '$serialnumber'", ARRAY_A);
```

When I vardump this, i get the following.

```
array(1) {[0]=>array(4) {["serialnumber"]=>string(10)"battery #2" ["batttype"]=>string(5) "NiCad" ["cells"]=>string(1) "8"["fullvolts"]=>string(6)"12.125"}}
```

So with that being said, I know that the query is working fine.  I know that I am receiving the information.  What I can't for the life of me figure out, is how to turn the results from each column into individual variables, so that I can insert each variable randomly throughout my page.

I have tried about 8 different methods so far.  I hope you guys can help!  thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the result:

```
foreach($editresult as $result) {
    $serialnumber = $result['serialnumber'];
    $batttype = $result['batttype'];
    $cells = $result['cells'];
    $fullvolts = $result['fullvolts'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If only one row is expected to be returned, you can do the following

```
$editresult = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `serialnumber`, `batttype`, `cells`, `fullvolts` FROM listbattery WHERE serialnumber = '$serialnumber'", ARRAY_A);
```

Then you can access returned values like

```
$editresult['serialnumber']
$editresult['batttype']
$editresult['cells']
$editresult['fullvolts']
```

or if you change `ARRAY_A` to `OBJECT`, you will be able to access these values like so

```
$editresult->serialnumber
$editresult->batttype
$editresult->cells
$editresult->fullvolts
```

There is no need in `get_results` and `foreach` like shown in @nanodanger's answer if you always expect to get only 1 row